# Honda Cr-V AC Died

Tags: honda, ac, hvac, replace

Recently my 2006 Honda Cr-V AC died - again. After researching I discovered I had "[black death](https://www.hexautoparts.com/blog/post/Honda-CRV-Black-Death-How-to-Identify-AC-Compressor-Black-Death-and-other-AC-System-Problems.html)" where the whole AC system is infected with little black chips To judge by the number of upset owners online, the problem occurs frequently to the CR-V compressor, and the replacement need $1650. The car has had three compressors. The first mechanic did not know about Black Death and put in a new Honda supplied compressor, which failed immediately. The next one lasted a year. My second mechanic found out about the problem after I gave him a heads up after I researched. Do I really need to do the Compressor, Condenser, Drier, and Evaporator?

Answer (score 1):

When the seals disintegrate moisture is introduced in the system. When refrigerant and moisture combine an acid is formed and when circulated it attacks all parts of the system i.e (condenser and evaporator coils, compressor, TX valve, and everything else as well). The debris from the O-ring clogs the TX (thermal expansion) valve preventing the flow of both refrigerant and lubricant to the compressor thereby overheating it and causing it to seize.
The only solution is replace everything with new components, tubing and seals etc.

Comment: [Here's a good explanation of Black Death](http://www.aircondition.com/tech/questions/15/What-is-Black-Death%3F) for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 0):

What did your research tell you? If the seals disintegrate to form these little "black chips" then, imho, all the pipes need to be cleaned / replaced as well. I would assume from what you say that all the items need to be replaced as trying to clean the Condenser, Drier, and Evaporator would be a fruitless process as it sounds like the chips will get permanently stuck in the fine tubes / fins.